# What's the matter?

Tags: parts-of-speech, subjects

> A (1). What’s wrong?      A (2). What’s the matter? 
>   B. The internet doesn’t work.

In A (1), ‘*what*’ is beyond doubt a subject. But in A (2), Which is the subject: ‘*what*’ or ‘*the matter*’? Can it be clearly designated? Or ambivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take *'s* to be a normal copular, then *what* is a subject-complement.

e.g.

> What is a car?
>   What is your name?

Both *a car* and *your name* are subjects, similarly to how [subject-auxiliary inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion) works.

However I would argue that such analysis is incorrect, as "what's the matter?" has become idiomatic and simply means "what's wrong?". So you can, in fact, argue that *the matter* in that instance can be seen as adjectival.

This is because you can say:

> What is [the matter/wrong] is that the house is on fire.

But not

> *What is a car is a fridge on wheels.

And thus *what* is a subject again.

Comment: When you said, before your update, ‘what’s the matter’ is an idiom, I dropped down the issue. and I didn’t refer anything about your saying that ‘what’ is the subject in ‘What is a car?’ But now the issue being developed into ‘subject-auxiliary inversion,’ I’d like to ask one thing. _“The matter is whether he has the right,”_ from this example, I can think Wh-movement in OP, which is linked from your link. That is, in _“What is the matter?”_, ‘what’ could be both subject as you say and the complement that is fronted, based on Wh-movement, I think. Can’t this possibility be accepted?

Comment: People usually say "the thing is", "the question is" or, if it's a problem, "the problem is". "The matter is" very old fashioned. But if that's where you're coming from then "what" becomes a subject-complement.